# Loading huge XML files and dealing with MemoryError

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, mediawiki

I have a very large XML file (20GB to be exact, and yes, I need all of it).  When I attempt to load the file, I receive this error:

```
Python(23358) malloc: *** mmap(size=140736680968192) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 5, in <module>
    code = xml.read()
MemoryError
```

This is the current code I have, to read the XML file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = open('pages_full.xml', 'r')
code = xml.read()
xml.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(code)
```

Now, how would I go about to eliminating this error and be able to continue working on the script.  I would try splitting the file into separate files, but as I don't know how that would affect BeautifulSoup as well as the XML data, I'd rather not do this.

(The XML data is a database dump from a wiki I volunteer on, using it to import data from different time-periods, using the direct information from many pages)

Comment: Do you have 20GB of ram? If not, even if you can get this to work it's going to be unbearably slow as it swaps in and out. There might be a way for you to operate on only chunks at a time with something like lxml, though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do *not* use BeautifulSoup to try and such a large parse XML file. Use the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead. Specifically, use the [`iterparse()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) to parse your file as a stream, handle information as you are notified of elements, then *delete* the elements again:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

parser = ET.iterparse(filename)

for event, element in parser:
    # element is a whole element
    if element.tag == 'yourelement'
         # do something with this element
         # then clean up
         element.clear()
```

By using a event-driven approach, you never need to hold the *whole* XML document in memory, you only extract what you need and discard the rest.

See the [`iterparse()` tutorial and documentation](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm).

Alternatively, you can also use the [lxml library](http://lxml.de/); it offers the same API in a faster and more featurefull package.