# Are there any benefits of using Beautiful Soup to parse XML over using lxml alone?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, lxml

I use Beautiful Soup often to parse HTML files, so when I recently needed to parse an XML file, I chose to use it. However, because I'm parsing an extremely large file, it failed. When researching why it failed, I was led to this question:  [Loading huge XML files and dealing with MemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924200/loading-huge-xml-files-and-dealing-with-memoryerror).

This leads me to my question:  If lxml can handle large files and Beautiful Soup cannot, are there any benefits of using Beautiful Soup instead of simply using using lxml directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this link about [BeautifulSoup Parser](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html):

"BeautifulSoup" is a Python package that parses *broken* HTML, while "lxml" does so faster but with high quality HTML/XML. So if you're dealing with the first one you're better off with BS... **but** the advantage of having "lxml" is that you're able to get the `soupparser`.

From that link I provided at the top it shows how you can use the capabilities of "BS" with "lxml"

**So in the end**... you are better off with "lxml".

Answer (score 1):

lxml is very fast, and is relatively memory efficient. BeautifulSoup by itself scores less well on the efficiency end, but is built to be compatible with non-standard / broken html and xml, meaning it is ultimately more versatile.

Which you choose to use is really just dependent on your use-case -- web scraping? probably BS. Parsing machine-written structured metadata? lxml is a great choice.

There is also the learning-curve to consider when making the switch - the two systems implement search and navigation strategies in slightly different ways; enough to make learning one system after starting with the other a non-trivial task.