# Removing specific elements from XML using Etree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to use Element tree to locate an element of interest from an XML and remove the entire group (i.e. the parent) from the XML.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree 

copasiML_str= IA.read_copasiML_as_string(model_file) # Reads XML as string
copasiML=ET.fromstring(copasiML_str) # parse XML to etree

for i in copasiML.findall(".//*[@name='ObjectCN']"): # locate element 
    if '[v18]' in  i.attrib['value']:           #search for 'v18' 
        if 'Parameter=V' in i.attrib['value']:   #search for 'Parameter=V'
            print i.attrib['value']             #Element identified
            parent = i.getparent()   #gets the parent of identified
            copasiML.remove(parent) # This does not work
```

This code identifies the element and gets the parent of the element I want to remove. Then it gives me an error when I try to remove the element:

```
ValueError: Element is not a child of this node.
```

The XML in question is fairly complicated. Here is a snippet:

```
<ParameterGroup name="FitItem">
            <ParameterGroup name="Affected Cross Validation Experiments">
            </ParameterGroup>
            <ParameterGroup name="Affected Experiments">
              <Parameter name="Experiment Key" type="key" value="Experiment_1"/>
              <Parameter name="Experiment Key" type="key" value="Experiment_2"/>
              <Parameter name="Experiment Key" type="key" value="Experiment_4"/>
            </ParameterGroup>
            <Parameter name="LowerBound" type="cn" value="1e-06"/>
            <Parameter name="ObjectCN" type="cn" value="CN=Root,Model=NoName,Vector=Reactions[V18],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=V,Reference=Value"/>
            <Parameter name="StartValue" type="float" value="0.1852208634119804"/>
            <Parameter name="UpperBound" type="cn" value="100"/>
          </ParameterGroup>
```

There are many 'FitItem' parameter groups. I'm trying to locate the one with '[V18]' and 'Parameter=V' and delete the entire FitItem. Would anybody know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it was a pasting error. The root is called copasiML.

Comment: Given that sample XML, parent of `*[@name='ObjectCN']` is the root element, that means you're trying to delete the entire XML which will make it not well-formed XML

Comment: Please recheck, I suspect in the actual code you use `lxml` (`etree.fromstring()` or similar) instead to populate `copasiML` variable, because built-in `ElementTree` doesn't have method `getparent()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the XML posted is only part of a larger XML and `<ParameterGroup name="FitItem">` isn't actually the root element, you should be able to remove element referenced by `parent` variable from it's parent (don't be confused) like so :

```
......
parent = i.getparent()
parent.getparent().remove(parent)
```

otherwise, you can't remove `parent` because it references the root element, and XML document requires exactly one root element to stay qualified as XML.

**This is a working example for demo :**

```
from lxml import etree

xml = '''<root>
    <ParameterGroup name="FitItem">
            <ParameterGroup name="Affected Cross Validation Experiments">
            </ParameterGroup>
            <ParameterGroup name="Affected Experiments">
              <Parameter name="Experiment Key" type="key" value="Experiment_1"/>
              <Parameter name="Experiment Key" type="key" value="Experiment_2"/>
              <Parameter name="Experiment Key" type="key" value="Experiment_4"/>
            </ParameterGroup>
            <Parameter name="LowerBound" type="cn" value="1e-06"/>
            <Parameter name="ObjectCN" type="cn" value="CN=Root,Model=NoName,Vector=Reactions[V18],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=V,Reference=Value"/>
            <Parameter name="StartValue" type="float" value="0.1852208634119804"/>
            <Parameter name="UpperBound" type="cn" value="100"/>
          </ParameterGroup>
</root>'''
copasiML=etree.fromstring(xml)
query = "//*[@name='ObjectCN'][contains(@value,'[V18]')][contains(@value,'Parameter=V')]"
for i in copasiML.xpath(query):
    parent = i.getparent()
    parent.getparent().remove(parent)

print etree.tostring(copasiML)
```

**output :**

```
<root>
    </root>
```

Comment: Hi har07. I though something like this should work however I a getting an AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'remove'

Comment: @user3059024 worked for me, try to run the demo code

Comment: Side note : BS is a possible alternative, but not really better than lxml in general. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351856/are-there-any-benefits-of-using-beautiful-soup-to-parse-xml-over-using-lxml-alon

Comment: Your strategy worked. The only change I made was to match the entire value of 'value'  (i.e.CN=Root,Model=NoName,Vector=Reactions[V18],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=V,Reference=Value"/>) and it worked. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Once I learned [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#), I never go back use use etree.

Note:

1. I added the root copasiML into your XML based on the comment
2. I added another FitItem with datafireball as the text just to show we locate
   the right element in the end.
3. In BeautifulSoup, I used two approaches to locate element `find(lamda)`, `find(args..)`, since you have quite a few rules locating FitItem while your find  parent logic is fairly simple.

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
myString = """
<ParameterGroup name="copasiML">
<ParameterGroup name="FitItem">
    <ParameterGroup name="Affected Cross Validation Experiments"></ParameterGroup>
    <ParameterGroup name="Affected Experiments">
      <Parameter name="Experiment Key" type="key" value="Experiment_1"/>
      <Parameter name="Experiment Key" type="key" value="Experiment_2"/>
      <Parameter name="Experiment Key" type="key" value="Experiment_4"/>
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Parameter name="LowerBound" type="cn" value="1e-06"/>
    <Parameter name="ObjectCN" type="cn" value="CN=Root,Model=NoName,Vector=Reactions[V18],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=V,Reference=Value"/>
    <Parameter name="StartValue" type="float" value="0.1852208634119804"/>
    <Parameter name="UpperBound" type="cn" value="100"/>
</ParameterGroup>
<ParameterGroup name="FitItem">Datafireball</ParameterGroup>
</ParameterGroup>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(myString, "xml")

def myfunc(e):
    try:
        if (e['name'] == 'ObjectCN') and (e.name == 'Parameter') and ('V18' in e['value']):
            return True
        else: 
            return False
    except:
        return False

target = soup.find(lambda x: myfunc(x))
parent = target.find_parent('ParameterGroup', {'name':'FitItem'})
parent.decompose()

print soup.prettify()
```

This is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ParameterGroup name="copasiML">
 <ParameterGroup name="FitItem">
  Datafireball
 </ParameterGroup>
</ParameterGroup>
```

Comment: Hi B.MR.W, thanks for responding. I tried your code and it seems that the soup.findall function is not finding anything (well it is returning 'None')

Comment: @user3059024 use find or find_all